# Ant: Unzip patternset not excluding META-INF and jUnit

Tags: java, ant, junit, unzip, meta-inf

Because some guys forgot to set the junit scope to "test", it has been packaged along with our libraries. Since we don't need junit in our final product, I wanted to exclude the class files in an unzip task.

**Note:** This task is necessary in the further build process, so leaving this out is not an option.

So far my unzip statement looks like this:

```
<unzip dest="${classes.dir}">
    <fileset refid="dependency.fileset"/>
    <patternset>
        <exclude name="META-INF/*"/>
        <exclude name="org/junit/**/*.class"/>
        <exclude name="junit/**/*.class"/>
    </patternset>
</unzip>
```

I tried various combinations, but the junit and META-INF files magically reappear each time.
As a work-around I added a delete statement with a fileset. It works but is completely unnecessary if I have the option to add a patternset to the unzip statement - in my opinion:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" casesensitive="false" includes="META-INF/*,junit/**/*,org/junit/**/*" />
</delete>
```

I already read through the manual, but found no clue on how to solve this problem.

Did I miss something, are the patterns incorrect or is it something else?

Comment: Isn't it easier to add scope tests where it was forgotten and rebuild everything?

Comment: not really, we use maven dependencies that weren't created by us.